# GWT request works twice, leads to process.waitFor interruption

Tags: java, gwt, download, glassfish-3

I have a long-running download process in my project, it lasts nearly 20 minutes, I download this file with FtpClient.retrieveFile() function. This download process done via another jar file which named DownloadVeDeploy.jar.

In my case download process starts, then after nearly 10 mins it starts for second time. 
My download implemantation like this ;

```
for (FTPFile file : ftpFiles) {
                        if (file.isFile()) {
                            output = new BufferedOutputStream(
                                    new FileOutputStream(downloadfolder + "/"
                                            + file.getName()));
                            conn.retrieveFile(
                                    ftpversion + "/" + file.getName(), output);
                            // Writing into target folder for build.xml
                            output.close();
                            System.out.println(file.getName()
                                    + " isimli dosya indirildi.");
                        }
                    }
```

Also I made a filter for not passing second request while it already has first request running. Here is the code;

```
private IslemBaslangici() {
    }

    public static void yeniIslem(String versiyonNo) {
        IslemBaslangici islemBaslangic = new IslemBaslangici();
        islemBaslangic.versiyonNo = versiyonNo;
        islemler.add(islemBaslangic);
        sonrakiIslem();
    }

    private static void sonrakiIslem() {
        IslemBaslangici islemBaslangici = null;
        if (islemler.size() > 0) {
            islemBaslangici = islemler.get(0);
            if (!islemBaslangici.calisiyor) {
                islemBaslangici.baslat(islemler.get(0));
                islemler.remove(islemBaslangici);
                sonrakiIslem();
            }
        }
    }
```

This code snippet lets only 1 process run a time and adds other requests to queue. So here is my question, why my download process repeats itself? I have a filter for multiple requests from client side, so it can't be from client side, and I call download process only once.

As an extra information, my project runs on Glassfish 3.1.2 .

Comment: Are there multiple files in the ftpFiles object?  Why is it a for loop if it should only be downloading one file?  Have you tried stepping throught he code with a debugger yet?

Comment: It downloads 3 different files, that's why I used loop. Only one instance is created and I did debug at local, it worked properly. I guess it's because network connection of local is good and process not last too long. But at remote server the connection is slow and download process lasts too long, and I guess retrieveFile method fires itself(if it's possible).